# Black screen through Hyperspin & Retroarch on all but the most recently loaded emulator

Tags: technical-issues, emulation, arcade, retroarch

I know this is specific, but it seems some other articles/posts run into a somewhat similar issue. I have Retroarch, and from the RocketLauncherUI I am able to successfully load all of the emulators I want to. However, from Hyperspin, only the most recently emulator loaded directly from Retroarch will successfully load, all others go to a black screen.

For example:

- I load Super Mario 64 (N64) from Retroarch using detect core - it loads perfectly.
- I then go into Hyperspin and load Goldeneye64 (N64) - no problem.
- Now if I go to load Sonic (Sega) the screen goes black.
- Back out of Hyperspin, open Retroarch, detect core load Sonic (Sega) - it loads fine.
- Go back to Hyperspin, load Lion King (Sega) and all is well.
- Go to load Goldeneye64 and get a black screen.

This can be repeated for other systems, so it seems it is dependent on the most recently loaded system.

I have turned on settings per core and turned them off. Off it loads a window  with an overflow of gibberish (likely from the bad core config). This goes for the settings in RocketLauncherUI and Retroarch. I can't figure it, but it is so close to working... Rather frustrating. Also, have the specific cores selected for each system in the system specific Retroarch configuration within RocketLauncherUI.

Any help is appreciated. Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the end I had to redo the Hyperspin to RocketLauncherUI Transition and Update process now all is well. Weird, but hope it helps someone in the future.